# i have installed Conntrack but not able to start minikube

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube, conntrack

I am trying to start Minikube but error

> Exiting due to GUEST_MISSING_CONNTRACK: Sorry, Kubernetes 1.28.3 requires crictl to be installed in root's path

NOTE : I have installed conntrack, docker ,kubectl also.

Comment: sudo minikube start --vm-driver=none

Comment: the error is shown after this step only...am i doing something wrong?